# Inspect value from channel

Tags: go, generator, goroutine

I have two read-only channels `<-chan Event` that utilized as generators.

```
type Event struct{
    time int
}
```

I can read their values as:

```
for {
    select {
    case <-chan1:
        // do something
    case <-chan2:
        //do something
    }
```

I use those channels for event-driven simulations so I have to choose the `Event` with the less `time` field.

Is it possible to inspect which value is going from each channel and only then choose from which one to read? Because the operation `<-chan1` takes value from channel and it is impossible to push it back (read only channel).

Comment: why do you create a local buffer and store every event in it, then select from that buffer?

Comment: @ParhamAlvani want to do it without local buffer. looking for elegant solution

Comment: As another suggestion, you can implement channels like structure with Mutex and CondVar. I can upload my implementation for you if you want this type of solution.

Comment: @ParhamAlvani it would be interesting to see it

Comment: That's not how channels work, and fundamentally you can't do that and retain the guarantees that channels provide. After "peeking" at the value in a channel, it's not guaranteed to be the same one, or there be a value at all once you actually receive. You could use a different data structure as shown below, but then you also lose the ability to use select directly in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement your version of go channel structure. for example following implementation act like go channel without size limit and you can inspect its first element.

```
package buffchan

import (
    "container/list"
    "sync"
)

// BufferedChannel provides go channel like interface with unlimited storage
type BufferedChannel struct {
    m *sync.Mutex
    l *list.List
    c *sync.Cond
}

// New Creates new buffer channel
func New() *BufferedChannel {
    m := new(sync.Mutex)
    return &BufferedChannel{
        m: m,
        l: list.New(),
        c: sync.NewCond(m),
    }
}

// Append adds given data at end of channel
func (b *BufferedChannel) Append(v interface{}) {
    b.m.Lock()
    defer b.m.Unlock()

    b.l.PushBack(v)
    b.c.Signal()

}

// Remove removes first element of list synchronously
func (b *BufferedChannel) Remove() interface{} {
    b.m.Lock()
    defer b.m.Unlock()

    for b.l.Len() == 0 {
        b.c.Wait()
    }

    v := b.l.Front()
    b.l.Remove(v)

    return v.Value
}

// Inspect first element of list if exists
func (b *BufferedChannel) Inspect() interface{} {
    b.m.Lock()
    defer b.m.Unlock()

    for b.l.Len() == 0 {
        return nil
    }

    return b.l.Front().Value
}

// AsyncRemove removes first element of list asynchronously
func (b *BufferedChannel) AsyncNonBlocking() interface{} {
    b.m.Lock()
    defer b.m.Unlock()

    for b.l.Len() == 0 {
        return nil
    }

    v := b.l.Front()
    b.l.Remove(v)

    return v.Value
}
```

Comment: `AsyncRemove` might be better named as `AsyncNonBlocking` - since there is nothing asynchronous there.